# Filesystemwatcher C# high CPU usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a very simple from example (console) of the filsystemwatcher to listen for changes on a single directory. I have then taken the exact code and used it in a very simple windows form that has just one list box for the console output, but I have spawned it as a thread - the console version uses 0% cpu whereas the same single thread uses 25% ANY Insights as to why ???

THREADED VERSION

```
 Thread pdfWatcher = new Thread(t => startFileWatcher(pdfStoragePath))
        { IsBackground = false };
        pdfWatcher.Start();
    }

private void startFileWatcher(string pdfOutputPath)
    {
        statusOutput.Items.Add("Starting Thread : File Watcher...");
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = pdfOutputPath;
            messageStatusWindow("Watching Path : [" + pdfOutputPath + "] For new PDF's");


            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;


            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";

            // Add event handlers.
            //watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnCreated;
            //watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            //watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            messageStatusWindow("Thread Started : File Watcher");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }
```

**CONSOLE VERSION**

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: FileWatcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }



        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = args[1];
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                 | NotifyFilters.Size;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnCreated;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;



            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
```

in a

Comment: You don't need a threaded version. You need a version that *doesn't* process the events in the main thread. Running the watcher on another thread won't prevent it from losing events it the event handlers take too long. You haven't posted the event handlers either, so it's hard to say what is going on. Writing and *reading* the console from another thread isn't helping either

Comment: Thanks for this

You helped me realise that  that I didn't need a threaded version, the actual filesystemwatcher is a dispatched thread itself - declared the filesystemwatcher object in the main thread, then used the event handlers to spawn the threads needed to be actioned. the loop was killing cpu in the thread.

Comment: Instead of creating new threads you can use async events and tasks. Even better, you can feed the events to an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.1) and have that do the actual job, getting in-order processing out of the box

Answer (score 1):

The line `while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;` is consuming all of your cpu. You must eigther use a message pump (no console application) or some kind of wait mechanism like `while(Console.Read()!='g') System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);`

Comment: Isn't Console.Read() waiting for input before returning control ?

Comment: This was the exact problem, thanks for the input much appreciated, have "dethreaded" the filewatcher and all is much better.